# C program:error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24

Tags: c, linux

When I run a C program, it keeps showing

```
sh: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24
sh: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24
sh: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24
sh: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24
sh: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24
```

I used the ps command to find out if there was another identical running program, but didn't find it.

Then I used the find command to find the location of **libc.so.6**.

```
  find / -name libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
  ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.27.so
```

I searched and tried many methods but could not solve the problem.
I hope someone can help me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet to understand the problem better ?

Comment: I don't have the source code and the errors above all occur when executing . /myApplication

Comment: Where did you get it? How do you know it's a  C program?

Comment: I just maintain the staff and another server ran the program and that was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Error 24 on x86-64 is `EMFILE`: Too many open files.

Your program has a serious bug: it leaks file descriptors.  It opens files, but never closes them.  Open file descriptors are limited, and your program has ran out.

The `sh:` at the beginning indicates that it is the POSIX shell that fails to run.  When you call `system()` or `popen()`, the specified string is actually run under `sh`.  The fact that there are a number of them leads me to believe it uses `popen()` a lot to run external commands, but never bothers to `pclose()` them.

If you *need* to run that program, you can try and paper over the serious bugs by increasing the descriptor limit, by running e.g. `ulimit -n 2048 && ./myApplication` (which raises the limit to 2048 open file descriptors).

To investigate exactly what the program is doing, look into `ltrace` (which tracks library calls the process does) and `strace` (which tracks system calls the process does), and exploring the program under `gdb` debugger.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't test it right now. I hope your answer will help someone who needs it.